# Open File Dialog (msoFileDialogOpen) with file already highlighted for user

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to open a file dialog box from Excel (VBA) with a particular file already selected - similar to when you open an html downloaded file with right-click "Show File in Folder".

The reason I need this is so that the user can right click and drag the file from the dialog box into an email as an attachment, or alternatively open it or copy it for pasting into another folder.

I have tried to filter the filename but that won't work.  Apparently we can only filter extensions.

```
Dim fDialog As FileDialog
Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

fDialog.Title = "Here is Your File"
fDialog.InitialFileName = "C:\Folder With Files\"
fDialog.Filters.Add "Custom PDF Files", "20200730_Xy.pdf", 1 ' Throws error here
fDialog.show
```

Comment: What happens when you set `fDialog.InitialFileName` to the full filepath `C:\Folder With Files\20200430_Xy.pdf`? According to the Microsoft docs: `If you specify a file that exists in the initial folder, only that file appears in the dialog box.` You can also use Wildcards to show multiple files. Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.filedialog.initialfilename

Comment: When setting fDialog.InitialFileName = "C:\Folder With Files\20200430_Xy.pdf" the correct folder opens with all files showing, none highlighted, and the filename "20200430_Xy.pd" showing in the File Name textbox.  I also tried changing msoFileDialogOpoen with msoFileDialogPicker, like in the doc.microsoft link with the same results

Comment: Solved with wildcard - sort of.  By replacing the first character in the file extensions with a wild card, like C:\whatEverfFileName.pdf to C:\whatEverFileName.*df it will bring only that file into the open dialog box.  The file is not highlighted, but since it is the only file showing in the dialog box it will be just as easy for the user to find it. Thanks iskyfire